# Delegating UI actions to ViewModel for execution

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an `ScrollViewer` which holds an `ItemsSource`. The items are bound to the ViewModel and are sorted in ascending order. The users are allowed to add items to this list, however, the list needs to be scrolled to bottom because of the sorting order. From what I found, `ScrollViewer` doesn't have a "lock to bottom" feature, but has a `ScrollToEnd` method which does what I'm looking for.

The problem though, is that the items are added in the ViewModel, and the ViewModel obviously doesn't have access to the View to call the `ScrollToEnd` method on the `ScrollViewer`. To get around this, I declared an action delegate in the ViewModel like this:

```
public Action ScrollAction { get; set; }
```

And set it in the View upon creation of the ViewModel:

```
viewModel.ScrollAction = () => scrollViewer.ScrollToEnd();
```

The delegate is executed in the ViewModel once an item is added to the list. Even though this works, it feels a little hacky to me, since this kind of breaks the isolation of the ViewModel from the View. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I like it. Testable. Separated enough.

Comment: Did you think about adding an attached behaviour to the SV?

Comment: @GarryVass What is SV?

Comment: I agree with @Garry Vass, an AttachedProperty or Behaviour on ScrollViwer would be a cleaner option

Comment: @PoweredByOrange, SV=ScrollViewer.  The point being to put a behaviour on it.  It's the conventional way to deal with these things in MVVM; it gets all that hacky stuff out of the View and VM.  I can write a skeleton for that, but don't know enough about what's driving your View to do it all.

Comment: @GarryVass An skeleton would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also vote for an AttachedProperty to your scroll viewer.

I created following attached property to bind scroll to end with a boolean variable.

```
public static class ScrollViewerBehavior
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollToRightEndProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ScrollToRightEnd", typeof (bool), typeof (ScrollViewerBehavior),
                                                new PropertyMetadata(false, OnScrollToRightEndPropertyChanged));

        public static bool GetScrollToRightEnd(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool) obj.GetValue(ScrollToRightEndProperty);
        }

        public static void SetScrollToRightEnd(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ScrollToRightEndProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnScrollToRightEndPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender,
                                                              DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var sv = sender as ScrollViewer;
            if (sv == null) return;

            if ((bool) e.NewValue)
            {
                sv.ScrollToRightEnd();
            }
            else
            {
                sv.ScrollToLeftEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

You can use this attached property in your XAML...

```
<ScrollViewer ... local:ScrollViewerBehavior.ScrollToRightEnd="{Binding IsScrolledToEnd}" ... />
```

Alternatively if you want to save the action delegate as in your question, you could do the following in the OnScrollToRightEndPropertyChanged method above.

```
.....
var viewModel = sv.DataContext as YourViewModel;
if (viewModel != null)
{
    viewModel.ScrollAction = () => sv.ScrollToRightEnd();
}
.....
```

Comment: Nice. The `AttachedProperty` idea is definitely better than my original implementation.